# Display a Sharepoint Calendar in Outlook Web Acces (not Outlook client)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, outlook

I need to add a Sharepoint Calendard in OWA.
I clicked on "add a calendar from the internet". I am able to enter the URL to my calendar, but not events are showing.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

From this article: [Import or subscribe to a calendar in Outlook on the web](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-subscribe-to-a-calendar-in-outlook-on-the-web-503ffaf6-7b86-44fe-8dd6-8099d95f38df), SharePoint calendar seems to be not supported in Outlook on the web.

> In Outlook on the web, you can import events from an .ics file to your
> existing calendar or subscribe to a calendar online and receive
> automatic updates (known as an ICS subscription or an iCal
> subscription). You can import calendars from websites or calendar
> programs that support the .ics file format, such as Apple iCal, Google
> Calendar, and Mozilla Lightning.

Comment: That's also the conclusion I came to when doing some research. Thanks for confirming it.